# Shortest distance between point and line (vectors)

Tags: vectors

If I am given position vector *$a$* and a line *$r = βb$*, how do I prove that the shortest distance is$ |a- ((a.b)/b^2 )b|$? I understand that somewhere the dot product is = $0$ but am unable to prove it. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve $u'(\beta)=0$ for $u:\beta\mapsto |a-\beta b|^2=|a|^2-2\beta(a\cdot b)+\beta^2|b|^2$. Calling the root $\beta_*$, the distance between $a$ and the line is $\sqrt{u(\beta_*)}$.